# How can I define a return type of void for a function in a Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
   network = (action): void =>{
        if (action) {
            this.action = action;
            this.net = true;
            this.netd = true;
        } else {
            this.action = null;
            this.net = false;
            this.netd = false;
        }
    }
```

I tried to define an interface but it's not working for me:

```
interface IStateService {
    network: (action: string): void;
}
```

I get a message saying "unexpected token" on void

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have two options for syntax for a function-typed interface member, which are equivalent here:

```
interface IStateService {
    network: (action: string) => void;
}
```

or

```
interface IStateService {
    network(action: string): void;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

That is close to the "type literal" syntax, but the braces are required for that:

```
interface IStateService {
    network: { (action: string): void; }
}
```

This is the full syntax, and allows defining overloads, like this:

```
interface IStateService {
    network: {
        (): string;
        (action: string): void;
    }
}
```